# Compactness Definition Concerning Accumulation Points

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Thus, the following are $\underline{\text{said}}$ to be equivalent:

> $\textbf{1.}$ The accumulation point(s) of $A$ belong to $A$.
>
> $\textbf{2.}$ $A$ is closed and bounded.
>
> $\textbf{3.}$ For every open cover $C$ of $A$, $\exists $ a finite subcover $C_1$ of $C$.
>
> > $\textbf{Question:}$ Concerning the equivalence of $1$ and $2$--Why is there the restriction that $A$ must be bounded? Isn't $A$ closed iff the accumulation point(s) of $A$ belong to $A$ as it is?

Note I am getting the definition of compactness partly from [here](http://math.umaine.edu/%7Efarlow/sec54.pdf).

Comment: I think $1$ is not equivalent to be compact, only to be closed. And is necessary to be bound. For example, consider $A=\mathbb{R}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the cover $(n-1,n+1)$. You cannot take a finite subcover.

Comment: It has been said that compact sets behave in some ways like finite sets. For example if $S$ is compact and not empty, and if $ f:S\to \Bbb R$ is continuous,  then $\{f(x): x\in S\}$ has a maximum and a minimum. (This is a special case of the fact that a continuous image of a compact set is also compact.)

Comment: #1 is (or is equivalent to, depending on which def'n you prefer). the statement that $A$ is closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stated theorem is incorrect. In particular, (2) and (3) are indeed equivalent (Heine-Borel) but the point (1) is in general weaker for arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. As a counterexample, consider the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains all of its accumulation points trivially but for which the open cover $$\mathcal{U} = \{ (-i,i) \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}$$ has no finite subcover. Further, $\mathbb{R}$ is not bounded.

Comment: Depending on the definition, $\infty$ can be an acc. point and is not contained in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I've never seen a definition of accumulation point that allows for points *outside* of the space. And indeed, the notes linked in the question use the usual definition in terms of neighbourhoods.

Comment: In fact, you can tell that infinity is not considered to be an accumulation point by the author by looking at the example where the author describes why $\mathbb{Z}$ has no accumulation points. If we were working in a compactification of the reals (as you are suggesting), then $\mathbb{Z}$ would have at least one accumulation point. It is clear that the author just made a mistake in the statement of the theorem.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider the set $[0,\infty)$. This is a closed set, but not compact. It does not contain the accumulation point at $\infty$. Of course, different books use different definitions for accumulation point so there might just be a misunderstanding.

If accumulation points are just limit points then $[0,\infty)$ contains all its accumulation points but is not compact, contradicting the equivalence they give.